# Drupal7: Form validation

Tags: php, drupal-7

I made a form in an custom module
I try to add validation for the textfield **'distance[postal_code]'**

But didn't work!

Who can help me?

Hook_menu:

```
function location_search_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['markten'] = array( //this creates a URL
    'title' => 'Markten, nog toegankelijker!', //page title
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
    'page arguments' => array('location_search_form'), //put the name of the form here
    'access callback' => TRUE
  );
  return $items;
}
```

The form:

```
    function location_search_form($form, &$form_state) {
      $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="postal-code-search"><h2>Markten vandaag in de buurt...</h2>';
      $form['#sufix'] = '</div>';
      $form['#attributes'] = array('id' => 'postal-code-form');
      $form['#method'] = 'get';
      $form['#action'] = '/location-list'; // make url 
      $form['distance[postal_code]'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', //postal code field
        '#size' => 10,
        '#maxlength' => 10,
        '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required
        '#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('Postal code')),
      );
 $form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Search'),
    '#name' => '', // unset 'op'
  );
      return $form;
    }
```

Validation:

```
function location_search_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $pc = $form_state['values']['distance[postal_code]'];
  if(empty($pc) || $pc == '') {
    form_set_error('distance[postal_code]', t('Postal code is required!'));
  }
}
```

Comment: '#required' is a validation for "empty value" :) if it's "true", the field need be filled. look for custom validation https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#element_validate

Comment: Hello, i now this '#required' function, but don't work. I try several ways to code this form but doesn't work. I don't know what i'm doing wrong (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$form['distance[postal_code]'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', //postal code field
        '#size' => 10,
        '#maxlength' => 10,
        '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required
        '#element_validate' => array('empty_element_validation'),
        '#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('Postal code')),
      );



function empty_element_validation($element, &$form_state, $form) {
   if (empty($element['#value'])) {
     //form_set_error('distance[postal_code]', t('Postal code is required!'));
     form_error($element, t('Postal code is required!'));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that the problem is in this code:

```
...
$form['#method'] = 'get';
$form['#action'] = '/location-list';
...
```

And this code:

```
...
$form['#after_build'][] = 'location_search_form_modify';
...
function location_search_form_modify($form){ // remove form_token, form_build_id, form_id from url
  unset($form['form_token']);
  unset($form['form_build_id']);
  unset($form['form_id']);
  return $form;
}
...
```

If the form submitted, it redirect to the 'get' url, and ignore the validation